# Filter treeNodes in Ant Design Tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using a [Searchable Tree](https://ant.design/components/tree/#components-tree-demo-search) component in Ant Design. I would like to filter treeNodes on search. So that if a search value is found, a treeNode is shown. If not, it is hidden (i. e. filtered).

There is a `filterTreeNode` prop in API. Is it possible to filter treeNodes (hide unrelevant treeNodes from search) with this prop? If not, how can achieve the desired result?

Here is my code for `filterTreeNode` function:

```
const filterTreeNode = (node) => {
  const title = node.title.props.children[2];
  const result = node.key.indexOf(searchValue) !== -1 ? true : false
  console.log(searchValue);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
};
```

I can see that the result (true or false) is logged in the console, but with the Tree itself nothing happens.

Here is a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tree-search-filter-lrv89?file=/index.js:0-3079) and the full code for the component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Tree, Input } from "antd";
import gData from "./gData.js";

const { Search } = Input;

const dataList = [];
const generateList = (data) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const node = data[i];
    const { key } = node;
    dataList.push({ key, title: key });
    if (node.children) {
      generateList(node.children);
    }
  }
};
generateList(gData);

const getParentKey = (key, tree) => {
  let parentKey;
  for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
    const node = tree[i];
    if (node.children) {
      if (node.children.some((item) => item.key === key)) {
        parentKey = node.key;
      } else if (getParentKey(key, node.children)) {
        parentKey = getParentKey(key, node.children);
      }
    }
  }
  return parentKey;
};

const SearchTree = () => {
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const onExpand = (expandedKeys) => {
    setExpandedKeys(expandedKeys);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const expandedKeys = dataList
      .map((item) => {
        if (item.title.indexOf(value) > -1) {
          return getParentKey(item.key, gData);
        }
        return null;
      })
      .filter((item, i, self) => item && self.indexOf(item) === i);
    if (value) {
      setExpandedKeys(expandedKeys);
      setSearchValue(value);
      setAutoExpandParent(true);
    } else {
      setExpandedKeys([]);
      setSearchValue("");
      setAutoExpandParent(false);
    }
  };

  const filterTreeNode = (node) => {
    const title = node.title.props.children[2];
    const result = title.indexOf(searchValue) !== -1 ? true : false;
    console.log(searchValue);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  };

  const loop = (data) =>
    data.map((item) => {
      const index = item.title.indexOf(searchValue);
      const beforeStr = item.title.substr(0, index);
      const afterStr = item.title.substr(index + searchValue.length);
      const title =
        index > -1 ? (
          <span>
            {beforeStr}
            <span className="site-tree-search-value">{searchValue}</span>
            {afterStr}
          </span>
        ) : (
          <span>{item.title}</span>
        );
      if (item.children) {
        return { title, key: item.key, children: loop(item.children) };
      }

      return {
        title,
        key: item.key
      };
    });
  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <Tree
        onExpand={onExpand}
        expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
        autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
        treeData={loop(gData)}
        filterTreeNode={filterTreeNode}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SearchTree />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the [API document](https://ant.design/components/tree/#Tree-props), `filterTreeNode` will **highlight** tree node, and will not hide it.

```
filterTreeNode

Defines a function to filter (highlight) treeNodes. When the function returns true, the corresponding treeNode will be highlighted
```

If you want to hide tree node, you will have  to manually filter it first before before passing it to `Tree` in loop function, something like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Tree, Input } from "antd";
import gData from "./gData.js";

const { Search } = Input;

const dataList = [];
const generateList = (data) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const node = data[i];
    const { key } = node;
    dataList.push({ key, title: key });
    if (node.children) {
      generateList(node.children);
    }
  }
};
generateList(gData);

const getParentKey = (key, tree) => {
  let parentKey;
  for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
    const node = tree[i];
    if (node.children) {
      if (node.children.some((item) => item.key === key)) {
        parentKey = node.key;
      } else if (getParentKey(key, node.children)) {
        parentKey = getParentKey(key, node.children);
      }
    }
  }
  return parentKey;
};

const SearchTree = () => {
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(gData);

  const onExpand = (expandedKeys) => {
    setExpandedKeys(expandedKeys);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value?.toLowerCase();
    const expandedKeys = dataList
      .map((item) => {
        if (item.title.indexOf(value) > -1) {
          return getParentKey(item.key, gData);
        }
        return null;
      })
      .filter((item, i, self) => item && self.indexOf(item) === i);
    if (value) {
      const hasSearchTerm = (n) => n.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1;
      const filterData = (arr) =>
        arr?.filter(
          (n) => hasSearchTerm(n.title) || filterData(n.children)?.length > 0
        );
      const filteredData = filterData(gData).map((n) => {
        return {
          ...n,
          children: filterData(n.children)
        };
      });

      setTreeData(filteredData);
      setExpandedKeys(expandedKeys);
      setSearchValue(value);
      setAutoExpandParent(true);
    } else {
      setTreeData(gData);
      setExpandedKeys([]);
      setSearchValue("");
      setAutoExpandParent(false);
    }
  };

  const filterTreeNode = (node) => {
    const title = node.title.props.children[2];
    const result = title.indexOf(searchValue) !== -1 ? true : false;
    console.log(searchValue);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  };

  const loop = (data) => 
    data.map((item) => {
      const index = item.title.indexOf(searchValue);
      const beforeStr = item.title.substr(0, index);
      const afterStr = item.title.substr(index + searchValue.length);
      const title =
        index > -1 ? (
          <span>
            {beforeStr}
            <span className="site-tree-search-value">{searchValue}</span>
            {afterStr}
          </span>
        ) : (
          <span>{item.title}</span>
        );
      if (item.children) {
        return { title, key: item.key, children: loop(item.children) };
      }

      return {
        title,
        key: item.key
      };
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <Tree
        onExpand={onExpand}
        expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
        autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
        treeData={loop(treeData)}
        filterTreeNode={filterTreeNode}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SearchTree />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation, but I thought may be there is some way to make it work as `filterTreeNode` in TreeSelect. Could you please share an example, how I can filter nodes before passing them to Tree?

Comment: @jupiteror check my edits. Something like: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tree-search-filter-forked-7cglm

Comment: Thank you very much! The only problem is that search is case sensitive. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @jupiteror you can either use regex of transform string using `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` before using `indexOf`. Updated my answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tree-search-filter-forked-7cglm

Comment: Could please share an example with using regex? In the current example if the search is 'Title' and the title itself is 'title', then it's working. When the search is 'title' and the title is capitalized ('Title'), then it's not working. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Also is there any way to optimize the performance? I have around 3000 nodes and I've already added `if (value && value.length > 2)` to `onChange` function, but the search is still very slow.

Comment: @jupiteror Code is doing too many things, only suggestions I would have is to 1. user virtual scroll 2. multiple places in code are searching for term, update data object so that search happens only once and not multiple time 3. Instead of searching on key change, may be search on blur

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! And what about this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386466/filter-treenodes-in-ant-design-tree/64416914?noredirect=1#comment113917464_64416914 on using regex?

Comment: You can build dynamic regex: `/(word to search)/gi` and do pattern matching with it.

Comment: BTW, if you want to use CheckBox at the same time, there is a problem  with this method: for example, the parent node NodeF has 3 nodes Child1, Child2, Child3, after filtering out Child1 and then checking Child1, NodeF will be automatically checked (it should be a half-checked state), then clear the Search, and you'll find that all the 3 Children are checked. One way I can think of is to hide the nodes that don't need to be displayed by `display:none`, so that the original function of CheckBox is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Couple weeks ago, i had to meet same like this client's enhancement. So how i did it was, we had Search over DirectoryTree and inside tree we rendered the nodes with a function

```
 <DirectoryTree
              onExpand={handleOperatorExpand}
              expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
              autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
              onSelect={handleOperatorSelect}
            >
              {renderTreeNodes(mtoCharts)}
            </DirectoryTree>
```

In search onChange event we saved values to a state, like searchValue. Then searchValue was checked in renderTreeNodes function with regex:

```
let dynamicRegex = `.*(${searchValue.toUpperCase()}){1}.*`;
```

if

```
item.name.match(dynamicRegex)
```

then we display the node otherwise we dont. SIMPLE !

**UPDATE : codes**

```
<Search onChange={handleOperatorChange} />

const handleOperatorChange = e => {
const { value } = e.target;
let temp = value.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()"'+@<>?\\\[\]]/g, '');

setSearchValue(temp);
setAutoExpandParent(true);};
```

and finally renderTreeNodes :

```
const renderTreeNodes = data =>
data &&
data instanceof Array &&
data.map(item => {
  const title = (
    <Highlighter
      highlightStyle={{ color: '#f50' }}
      searchWords={[searchValue]}
      autoEscape={true}
      textToHighlight={item.name}
    />
  );

  if (searchValue) {
    let dynamicRegex = `.*(${searchValue.toUpperCase()}){1}.*`;
    if (!isEmpty(item.children)) {
      // let doesChildrenHaveMatchingName = false;
      // item.children.forEach(itemChild => {
      //   if (itemChild.name.match(dynamicRegex)) {
      //     doesChildrenHaveMatchingName = true;
      //   }
      // });
      // if (doesChildrenHaveMatchingName) {
      return (
        <TreeNode
          className={!item.active ? 'dim-category' : ''}
          key={item.code}
          title={title}
          id={item.id}
          code={item.code}
          level={item.level}
          parentId={item.parentId}
          parentReference={item.path}
          icon={({ expanded }) => (
            <Icon type={expanded ? 'folder-open' : 'folder'} style={{ color: '#32327f' }} />
          )}
        >
          {renderTreeNodes(item.children)}
        </TreeNode>
      );
      // }
    }

    if (item.name.match(dynamicRegex) || item.path.match(dynamicRegex)) {
      return (
        <TreeNode
          className={item.active ? 'false' : 'dim-category'}
          key={item.code}
          title={!item.leaf ? title : getMtoTitle(item, title)}
          {...(item.leaf ? { leaf: item.leaf } : {})}
          id={item.id}
          code={item.code}
          level={item.level}
          parentId={item.parentId}
          parentReference={item.path}
          icon={({ expanded }) => {
            return item.leaf ? (
              <Icon type="money-collect" style={{ color: '#47bfa5' }} />
            ) : (
              <Icon type={expanded ? 'folder-open' : 'folder'} style={{ color: '#32327f' }} />
            );
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  } else {
    if (!isEmpty(item.children)) {
      return (
        <TreeNode
          className={!item.active ? 'dim-category' : ''}
          key={item.code}
          title={title}
          id={item.id}
          code={item.code}
          level={item.level}
          parentId={item.parentId}
          parentReference={item.path}
          icon={({ expanded }) => (
            <Icon type={expanded ? 'folder-open' : 'folder'} style={{ color: '#32327f' }} />
          )}
        >
          {renderTreeNodes(item.children)}
        </TreeNode>
      );
    }

    return (
      <TreeNode
        className={item.active ? 'false' : 'dim-category'}
        key={item.code}
        title={!item.leaf ? title : getMtoTitle(item, title)}
        {...(item.leaf ? { leaf: item.leaf } : {})}
        id={item.id}
        code={item.code}
        level={item.level}
        parentId={item.parentId}
        parentReference={item.path}
        icon={({ expanded }) => {
          return item.leaf ? (
            <Icon type="money-collect" style={{ color: '#47bfa5' }} />
          ) : (
            <Icon type={expanded ? 'folder-open' : 'folder'} style={{ color: '#32327f' }} />
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Could you please share you `onChange` and `renderTreeNodes` functions?

Comment: And also could you please share you `onSearch` function as well?

Comment: @jupiteror answer updated . you are welcome hope this helped